# I'm getting squares when trying to draw cyrillic characters with pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, cyrillic

I'm developing an app with Python 2.7 and Pygame (using Anaconda). In the app, I'm trying to draw text with Cyrillic characters, and it never displays right. I'm aware that it might be an encoding issue, so I included this line on the top of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

... and then I include a 'u' in front of each string I pass. This helped, but only partially - now, instead of wrong characters I get squares!

What's interesting is that the console prints out everything just fine.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you include some example characters with your question? I want to try this but I don't know what kind of characters might cause this.

Comment: The font you are using to render text, does it supports Cyrillic characters?

Comment: I'm using several fonts, including Times New Roman. As far as I'm aware, at least TNR should support cyrillic chars... 

As an example, try this word:
"разходка"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen because the font you are using for rendering text, is lacking Cyrillic characters. Try to find a font that is 100% Cyrillic, then render text in following way:

```
my_font = pygame.font.Font("path/to/cyrillic_font.ttf", 12)
text_surface = my_font.render(u"Текст", True, (255, 255, 255))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turned out to be a font problem indeed. I hadn't realized I was using for tests a font which doesn't support Cyrillic characters. 
Just for the record: even with the right font, you need to include the 'u' in front of each string you're passing. Also, in case you're combining two or more strings, each of them needs the 'u', or you'll get an ASCII error ("smt like can't convert character". 
Thank you all!